# Does making a pdf searchable make it more vulnerable?

Tags: vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, pdf

I would like to know if making a pdf 'searchable' somehow make it less secure?

Comment: Secure against what? It obviously makes the content more accessible to a person who knows how to use the search function, but I don't know if that would be a security issue...

Comment: More vulnerable to what?

Answer (score 1):

If you are somehow making it indexable by search engines (like uploading it to the web), and considering that 'secure' in this mean is 'making the content unknown', then yes. Every word will be a keyword. If secure means, in other context, 'making content non-replicable', then the same applies.

Otherwise, if your need of security is to guarantee your .PDF file is yours and none's else, making it searchable won't change a thing.